# Ajax Response not showing in blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a little issue with my code.

I have one dropdown field in my form. I applied onclick event onto it. Onclick, I' m sending ajax call to controller where I'm calling my query to fetch all the list of years and returning it back to blade in response.

My code is working and I can see the ajax response in preview under Network tab but the issue is that the values are not showing on blade into dropdown.

Blade

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <select id="regist_year" data-dependent="registration">
             <option selected value=""></option>
       </select>
   </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#regist_year').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    var all_years = $(this).data('dependent');

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('getAllyears') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{_token:_token,all_years:all_years},

        success:function(result)
        {
             $('#'+all_years).html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function getAllyears(Request $request)
{

    $all_years = $request->get('all_years');

    $years = DB::table('auto_databases_one')
        ->select('year')
        ->distinct()
        ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
        ->get();

    $get_years = '<option value="">Select ' . ucfirst($all_years) . '</option>';
    foreach ($years as $row) {
        $get_years .= '<option value="' . $row->year . '">' . $row->year . '</option>';
    }
    echo $get_years;
}
```

Comment: Is there an element with `id="registration"`? None is shown. Also not a good idea to use click event on a `<select>` as it will trigger both on open and selecting

Comment: @N69S As I wrote above, I can see the response that is full list of dropdown in network tab but it's not showing in my blade into dropdown.

Comment: @charlietfl What do you suggest to use then for select ?

Comment: @charlietfl My values are showing but when I selected the value of dropdown, it got changed to select again !

Comment: Not normal to put new options in the select that was just used to be honest. Whey do you need to replace them? A more common approach is have a selection populate another element. How would user even know you changed the options if they are in the same one?

Comment: @charlietfl
I resolved it myself.
$('#select_id').focus(function() worked for me !!!!!! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you're putting hyml into `$('#'+all_years)` wich is `$('#regist_year').data('dependent');` wich leads to `$('#registration')` and you have no dom with that ID

change it to

```
$('#regist_year').html(result);
```

Also, preventing default on a click on a select might have bad consequences. like dropdown not opening and option not selectable by mouse

Comment: My value are showing now but there is another issue. I just removed prevent default but when I select nay value, it gets disappeared !!!

Comment: @Shaan yop, that's for having the event trigger on click

Comment: I resolved it myself.
$('#select_id').focus(function() worked for me !!!!!! Thanks for your time.